# IOS: How can I use github to upload and share it to client?

Tags: ios, git, github

I am having one issues with Github. My client shared me a github link. What I need to do is i need to upload my project in that and commit. Some of my friends suggested me to use Terminal but i am uncomfortable with Terminal can any one help on how to do it.

Thank you,
Chandra.

Comment: Your trying to do this on iOS?  I'm not aware of a git iOS client.  for windows I'd suggest tortoise git and for mac "source tree".  Github has their own gui client for both OSes as well. (mac.github.com and windows.github.com)

Comment: Do you have a github account and permission to his repo ?

Comment: What kind of link was shared? A link to a repository? GitHub has a Mac client: http://mac.github.com/

Comment: @jeremy, Thanks for your response. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @MikeD, I have a link like  https://github.com/Clinet/Project

Comment: Have you already set up your project to use git?

Comment: @MikeD, No Mike. As I am new bee I don't know how to do that, Can you please suggest?

Comment: Does the project on github already have files included?

Comment: @MikeD, Sorry for not informing you. I completed this task. Thank you very much for your support